# Use DBus daemon to exchange message from C application to python application

Tags: python, linux, dbus

Hi I am pretty new to DBus daemon and would like to accomplish simple message exchange between C application and python application, which are running on custom linux-like environment. My understanding is

1. First, start dbus-daemon from init file
2. Register the C application and the python application to the D-BUS
3. Send message
   (it's just a simple string) on the bus between these 2 applications.

My questions are regarding (2) and (3) above. How can C application and python application register to the same bus?

Also, what APIs need to be invoked to send string messages between these 2 applications?

Answer (score 1):

*[You asked for simple message passing]*

### Do you really need DBus?

If you're asking for simple message passing between a C app and Python, why not use a message-passing library like Rabbit/ZeroMQ? Those already solve all the issues related to passing/receiving messages.

And, if you want to keep dependencies to a minimum, you could use a UNIX socket or even some simple TCP/UDP datagrams.

EDIT: Since I'm trying to convince you to research ZeroMQ as your IPC platform and how simple it is, here's a sample C "Client" sending a complete datagram to the server, which replies back.

[**ZeroMQ Client** Example in C:](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:hwclient)

```
// Hello World client
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ( void )
{
    printf ( "Connecting to hello world server…\n" );
    void *context   = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket ( context, ZMQ_REQ );
    zmq_connect ( requester, "tcp://localhost:5555" );

    int request_nbr;
    for ( request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++ ) {
        char buffer [10];
        printf ( "Sending Hello %d…\n", request_nbr );
        zmq_send ( requester, "Hello", 5, 0 );
        zmq_recv ( requester, buffer, 10, 0 );
        printf ( "Received World %d\n", request_nbr );
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

And the server is just as simple:

[**ZeroMQ Server** Example in C](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:hwserver)

```
// Hello World server

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main ( void )
{
    // Socket to talk to clients
    void *context   = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket ( context, ZMQ_REP );
    int rc = zmq_bind ( responder, "tcp://*:5555" );
    assert ( rc == 0 );

    while ( 1 ) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv ( responder, buffer, 10, 0 );
        printf ( "Received Hello\n" );
        sleep ( 1 );                                // Do some 'work'
        zmq_send ( responder, "World", 5, 0 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was looking into DBUS since it abstracts away the low level details of socket. C-application can continuously send string message and Python application needs to receive them all. And this process runs forever.

Comment: ZeroMQ/RabbitMQ have the same properties (You just receive "bundles" of data, and you don't need to unpickle them or worry about framing/paging/incomplete data etc, each data frame comes in whole) and you have the benefit of it being fully portable. Both applications could run in  Windows or OSX with the same intercomm framework.

Comment: The OP asked for information on DBUS which is a message passing system. ZeroMQ/RabbitMQ/ApacheMQ etc. are larger platforms and require more resources in comparison.  Usually they run on their own VM/hardware, and pass messages between servers.  DBUS is limited to messages on the same system and is very fast and light weight.

Answer (score 0):

There are two default buses on each Linux system - the system bus (shared for all users, made for system services) and the session bus. All DBus libraries let you trivially connect to one of those buses.

Then, in the receiver process, you need to take ownership of a bus name (a string that will let other processes find you), and register an object providing some methods. And then you will be able to call those methods from another process.

The best DBus API for C is https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html and the best API for Python is https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus

Comment: Actually, there is only the system bus started by default. The user bus must be started by the user.

Comment: Is there a way to send message from a daemon to some session bus? There could exist many session bus - each for each session. I known how to call ConsoleKit to obtain session name (passing pid), but don't known how to utilize this data.